# Selecting numbers from a set

Tags: combinatorics

How many numbers need to be selected from {1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15} to ensure that at least one pair of these numbers adds up to 16

The answer is 5 but I am unsure how to arrive at this answer

Comment: Use the pigeon-hole principle.

Comment: the pair you are looking for is {1,3,5,7}. or may be i understood question in wrong way

Answer (score 3):

Your set has $8$ numbers. What pairs add up to $16$? Let's list them.

$15 + 1$
$13 + 3$
$11 + 5$
$7 + 9$

So we can see that we can pick $4$ numbers from the set -- e.g. $1,3,5,9$ or $15,13,11,7$ without getting a pair that adds up to $16$. But when we pick the fifth number, we must get that a pair. That's because there are only four possible pairs, so the most numbers we can pick without getting a pair is $4$.

To make it totally clear: suppose you pick $4$ numbers. Suppose you picked $1,3,5,9$. Then there are only $4$ other numbers you can pick: $7,11,13,15$. Regardless of which one of those $4$ you pick, one of them will make a pair with the one of the numbers you've already picked.

This is an application of the **pigeon-hole principle**.